# Green cursor in ShareLaTeX - Lost functionalities

Tags: copy-paste, sharelatex

After some weeks working with ShareLaTeX, the cursor has turned green. This wouldn't be a great concern but since then I am unable to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> chunks of text in my text file when I am editing. I am also unable to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> find functionality and the "cut" function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

I can copy-paste using the mouse at least but I would like to be able to work only with the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've changed the key bindings to Emacs - associated with a green cursor. Change it back to None:

[image]

Vim key bindings will highlight with a red cursor.